# Как по Ctrl+C выйти из одной функции и продолжить выполнение в другой?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт

```
def One():

...

def Two():

...

def Three():

...
```

и т.д.

Необходимо нажать Ctrl+C, чтобы выйти из выполнения функции One(), но продолжить выполнять функцию Two(). Как можно такое реализовать?

Answer (score 8):

Нужно перехватить исключение KeyboardInterrupt.
Пример программы:

```
from time import sleep

def One():
    print "Proceesing One"
    sleep(10)

def Two():
    print "Proceesing Two"
    sleep(1)

def Three():
    print "Processing Three"
    sleep(1)

try:
    One()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Catched KeyboardInterrupt exception"
Two()
Three()
```

Comment: Всем спасибо!

Comment: ну дак раз спасибо, выберите верный ответ.

Answer (score 7):

Нажатие сочетания клавиш Ctrl+C генерирует исключение KeyboardInterrupt, поэтому:

```
try:
    One()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    Two()
```

Comment: я хз, except KeyboardInterrupt: не приходит никогда!